# Getting Data-ID "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

I used [floatingMenu](https://github.com/vladthecodeimpaler/floatingMenu)
 and I want get ID numbers with `Data-id` but I can not get the ID number of the buttons

Output:

```
example.com/?id=undefined
```

Why am I getting this error?

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector('.designer-actions');

$.floatingMenu({
    selector: '.designer-actions a[data-action="show-actions-menu"]',
    items: [{
        title: 'Open',
        action: 'https://example.com/?id=' + myDiv.dataset.idNo
    }, ]
});
```

```css
ul.floating-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px
}

ul.floating-menu[data-fm-floated="top"]:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 9px solid #000
}

ul.floating-menu[data-fm-floated="left"]:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
    right: -9px;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
    border-left: 9px solid #000
}

ul.floating-menu[data-fm-floated="right"]:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
    left: -9px;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid #000
}

ul.floating-menu[data-fm-floated="bottom"]:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #000
}

ul.floating-menu li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%
}

ul.floating-menu li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 32px
}

ul.floating-menu li .fm-icon {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #fff
}

ul.floating-menu.animated {
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.2s
}

ul.floating-menu.visible-transit {
    -o-transition: .2s;
    -ms-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

[data-fm-floated="left"].fadeInPosition {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

[data-fm-floated="right"].fadeInPosition {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    animation-name: fadeInRight
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

[data-fm-floated="top"].fadeInPosition {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

[data-fm-floated="bottom"].fadeInPosition {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://test3.moverals.com/mdm/floating-menu.js"></script>

<div id='designer-actions' class='designer-actions'>
    <a class='icon ion-ios-more' data-idNo='1' href='javascript:void(null);' data-action='show-actions-menu' data-fm-floatTo='right'>Button1</a>
    <a class='icon ion-ios-more' data-idNo='2' href='javascript:void(null);' data-action='show-actions-menu' data-fm-floatTo='right'>Button2</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/ne7g1996/)

Comment: There are several issues. Firstly `designer-actions` is an `id`, not a `class`, so your selector is wrong. Secondly, the `data-idNo` attribute is on the child `a` elements, so wouldn't be found by selecting the `div` element anyway

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I fixed but I'm getting same mistake

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer:

You need to loop through the array:

```
$('.designer-actions a').each(function(){
  idNo = $(this).data('idno');
  $.floatingMenu({
      selector: '.designer-actions a[data-action="show-actions-menu"]',
      items: [{
        title: 'Open',
        action: 'https://example.com/?id=' + idNo
      }, ]
  });
});
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns a single element, never an array. I think you're confusing it with `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan was right. You had some errors in your code. You need to select the a-elements with `$('.designer-actions a')`. I also correct a case-sensitive problem with idNo: https://jsfiddle.net/WalterIT/ne7g1996/4/